# Issue in producing arrays out of tiff images

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library, glob, tiff

My main aim is to produce 1D array out of each image in the 'dengue' folder. For which I used below code to read the file using both PIL and GLOB.

from PIL import Image
import glob

```
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('./dengue/*.tiff'): 
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

OUTPUT IS -

```
UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file './dengue/image_2016-09-18.tiff
```

How to resolve this? The same error showed up for numerous other images.

Or is there any other way I can read each of these tiff images to produce 1D array out of them? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: When I used just the glob all the images in the folder "dengue" did read. The code I used is below.                                                                                                                                                '''                                                                                                                                       
import glob2
dengue_files = glob2.glob('./dengue/*.tiff')
dengue_files                                                                                                                                        ```

Comment: This can happen whenever PIL does not support the image format, or whenever there's corrupted data in one of the image files. use a `try: except:` block around `Image.open()` and print out the problematic files for further investigation (ie: figure out how they're different from images that work fine)

Comment: [New-ish versions of Pillow fully support tiff](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#tiff), so I would lean towards non-standard or corrupted tiff files.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following tools to see the difference between a TIFF file you can read and one you cannot:

```
exiftool UNHAPPY.TIF
```

or, with `tiffinfo` from `libtiff`:

```
tiffinfo UNHAPPY.TIF
```

or, with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick identify -verbose UNHAPPY.TIF
```

My guess would be you have an unsupported compression or pixel type.

Comment: Tiff with old style JPG compression is not supported by ImageMagick  (libtiff)

Comment: Thank you Mark.