# PIL - "UNRECOGNIZED IMAGE MODE" when copy TiffImageFile

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I load a TIFF file with PIL and iterate on each page with enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(img)). Then I have my page as TiffImageFile and try to copy to apply treatments on it. But when I try to copy it, I have the error "unrecognized image mode". When I check, the image mode seems to be 1.

How can I handle with it please?

My code :

```
img = Image.open(path)
img.load()
for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(img)):
    page_to_update = page.copy()
```

Comment: `image` is not the same as `img`.

Comment: Sorry I edited ^^

Comment: Try `print(page)` to check its attributes.

Comment: I got this when print img :
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=1 size=1710x3561 at 0x7F828E48B070>

Comment: Not sure what's going on without seeing your image. Some suggestions here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69981762/2836621 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69423137/2836621

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will check this

Comment: I still have my error and can't find any solution...

This is the result of tiffinfo for one page :

TIFF Directory at offset 0x150aa (86186)
  Subfile Type: (0 = 0x0)
  Image Width: 1710 Image Length: 3561
  Resolution: 300, 300 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 1
  Compression Scheme: LZW
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 3561
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Predictor: none 1 (0x1)